# Why is TypeScript not letting me query a Meteor collection?

Tags: meteor, typescript

I'm using the packages `meteortypescript:compiler` and `meteortypescript:typescript-libs`. I'm trying to query a collection for a record like this:

```
MyCollection.findOne({email: 'user@example.com', username: 'bob'});
```

And I'm getting this error:

```
error TS2345: Argument of type '{ email: string; username: string; }'
is not assignable to parameter of type 'Selector'.
```

This makes no sense, because I can see that the type `Selector` in the `.d.ts` file I'm  using for Meteor is defined as `interface Selector extends Object {}`, which should not be giving a problem. Any pointers?

Comment: How did you initialise your collection? For example: _Base.Collections.Channels = new Mongo.Collection<Base.IChannel>("channels");_

Comment: Looks like you are using definitelytyped. You need to update your `meteor.d.ts` to the latest one. See [this update](https://github.com/DanielRosenwasser/DefinitelyTyped/commit/b0c077fdd39f2b901677a5d58155f516f66f88d1).

Comment: Thanks Jesse. Turns out that the update to `meteortypescript:typescript-libs` that fixes this apparently hasn't gone out yet, so I manually did it and it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine `interface Selector extends Object {}` with `Argument of type '{ email: string; username: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Selector'.` leads me to think you have a [freshness](http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/freshness.html) aka [strict object checking](http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/types/freshness.html) problem. Here is a simplified example:

```
interface Selector extends Object {}

function foo(arg:Selector){}
foo({ email: 'asfd@asdf.com', username: 'asdf' }); // same error you are getting
```